# CRC64 collisions analysis

Tags: probability, algorithms, cryptography

CRC64(s) is a 64-bit value, where s is a string of an arbitrary length. The change of one character causes the value of CRC64 to change. All values are used. Does this mean that the probabity of

$$CRC64(s_1) = CRC64(s_2) = \frac{1}{2^{64}},$$

given $s_1$ and $s_2$ are arbitrary strings (length and contents are unknown)?

(I think this is the case but maybe we need to apply more properties of CRC...)

Comment: In many a practical sense you are correct. The distribution of the 64-bit CRC tag is uniform. My inner nitpicker wants to make this more precise by saying that it holds when we constrain the message $s$ to be a random binary string of length $\ge64$ and $\le M$ for some integer $M\ge64$. We need the lower bound to the length of $s$ to make the probability of collisions $>0$. We need the upper bound to be able to use the uniform distribution for $s$. Otherwise the answer will depend on the probability distribution of the input $s$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why don't you expect collisions for M < 64 ?

Comment: I need to rethink that part, sorry...